# How much does resource quality really matter?

Tags: firefall

In Firefall, every resource has a quality of 1-1000, this gets transfered to gear when you craft it (for example, a minigun crafted with resource 543 will have quality 543). My question is how much does quality really matter. Will a tier 2 item pretty much ALWAYS be better than a tier 1 regardless of quality? Does quality increase things like DPS, clip size, accuracy, etc. or does it just modify constraints (that's all I noticed when crafting my tier 1 gun).

In short. Should I be picky about what quality I craft with?

**EDIT: With Game updates this question is no longer valid as game updates have removed the quality system alltogether**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes. A T1 item made with high-quality materials should approximately match (if I'm not mistaken) a T2 one made with low-quality stuff.

Somewhat longer: gear is made of subcomponents. Each of those subcomponents' quality increases a single attribute of the final piece from its base attributes. For example, a rifle barrel will probably affect damage per round, while a magazine will affect magazine size. Higher tier equipment will use more subcomponents and thus allow for greater overall customisability, and also have higher base attributes.

Also keep in mind that using higher-quality materials will increase an item's power and mass requirements, so you may want to use more basic materials for subcomponents you consider less important.

Comment: so then anything under say.. 500 quality I shouldnt use for crafting?

Comment: @JLaBella You should be basing your standards on how long you expect to have use that piece of gear. Waiting until you have all high quality minerals will hurt you early on, but late game you should have exacting standards because you will be using the gear for a longer period of time.

Comment: @JLaBella For attributes you care about, that's a reasonable threshold.

Later, your frame's constraints start mattering more than they do initially, and then you may want to sacrifice an unimportant attribute (use the lowest possible quality materials for it) so you have more power to spare.

Comment: @Lawton : and how long you'll be using it is affected by what level of structural reinforcement you can afford ... which you're probably not going to be buying high levels of, if at all, as you're starting out.

Comment: @Joe Its been a while since I played so I am not familiar with structural reinforcement, but I assume it functions similar to some of the CBT stuff, in which case that makes sense

Comment: @Lawton : it affects item durability (which as best I can tell is how much damage it can take over its lifetime, so you can't just keep repairing something over and over again).  And it's not craftable, it must be purchased with crystite or occassionally found for the low level ones.